# large image causes browser scroll

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm having trouble with a large image on my page, I can't seem to avoid it causing a scroll on certain browsers. So far I can only see it on Safari, but my friend apparently also sees it on Chrome.

All I'm doing, is positioning an image inside its container absolutely, and then moving it right, so that it actually outside of the container and wrapper. The problem is, that it's quite a large image, so in some browsers, you are able to scroll to the right revealing the rest of the image. Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background: aqua;
            margin: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        #wrapper{
            background: #fff;
            width: 960px;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #content{
            width: 960px;
            height: 500px;
            background: yellow; 
            position: relative;
        }
        #image{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -320px;
            z-index: 0;
            width: 1210px;
            height: 468px;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's a fiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/alsweeet/5mqHf/

Adding the overflow-x: hidden to the body style seems to solve the problem in most browsers, but not safari. You will see that I have not added this yet into the fiddle demo, and once you add it, you won't be able to scroll left or right anymore, which is the effect I'm trying to achieve cross browser.

I would sure appreciate some advice on this one. I'm sure there's probably a better way of doing this than absolutely positioning it.

Thanks!

Alsweeet

edit: problem IS occurring on Chrome also, the scroll bar is hidden, but you are still able to scroll sideways. Still works fine in Fire fox though.

edit: here's a screenshot to help explain what I'm trying to achieve without any side scroll. The red box is the box which is causing the side scroll. You can see that the red box is outside of the 960 wrapper.

[image]

Comment: What exactly want to do ? The scroll bar is coming fine to me in jsfiddle. The only change I would like to suggest make content height as 100%.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain it very well. I don't want the user to be able to scroll left or right. The page is a standard 960px wide site which is centered in the browser. But with this absolute dive going of to the right, the user can scroll away from the site to the right, I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Ok, now can you tell me about you image size ? I am assuming it must be gratter than 960px right?

Comment: yes it is, you can see its attributes in the css listed under #image. it is also pushed out of the container to the right, which doesn't help matters!

Answer (score 1):

overflow-x: is not fully cross browser compatible, try using `overflow:hidden;`, as long as you don't need to scroll vertical on the element then that will never cause you an issue.

A workaround to have overflow-y on an element and restrict the overflow-x on another element is this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mqHf/7/ - Fix for image position

A consideration for this is that if you are going to scroll vertically, when looking at the width of the image element, you need to account for the wdtih of a scrollbar to avoid a horizontal scroll bar, this usually varies between 15px and 30px depending on the browser.

Comment: heres a nice thread on overflow-x and overflow-y support.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=583696

Comment: ok thanks, unfortunately vertical scrolling is required though :/

Comment: i think your onto something there, i'm having a play around with it now, the problem i'm having now is its not showing the red box to the right.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? do you mean the image isn't being positioned correctly? I have edited it and moved the image the background of the #image element, this allows you to position the image correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/5mqHf/7/

Comment: sorry, yes, the image isn't going out to the right like in my fiddle demo. On the actual site, the red box is an image with glow around it, and it needs to be visible outside of the 960 container. can i screen shot on this? that would save me some trouble :P

Comment: I've added a screen shot to the question

Answer (score 1):

this is what you are looking for?

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/5mqHf/4/

Comment: sorry i can't see what you've changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look. Is it matching your requirements. if no please let me know so I can try something more.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/FyJ4F/

Comment: hey, i'm afraid that I have to keep the element to the right, thats the problem. I need to have an element which will go outside the wrapper to the right, but i need the browser scrolling to ignore it.

Comment: hey thanks, but like I said, adding overflow-x: hidden doesn't work in safari and chrome, it hides the scroll bar but you are still able to scroll left and right (either with a trackpad or a scroll wheel that goes left to right)